# Not able to connect to Hue web UI from Cloudera Manager

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloudera, hue, cloudera-manager, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I have installed Cloudera Express on Google cloud platform vm instance using Cloudera Manager.All the web services are running but web UI links of all services (Hue, Hbase, Spark etc.) are not loading.I can't reach the login page also .It gives the error as given below:

This site can’t be reached

instance-1.c.cluster-183105.internal’s server DNS address could not be found.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN[pls find the screenshot of error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEvoZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

You're configurations in Cloudera Manager are pointing to internal DNS records.

So, for example, Cloudera Manager does a health check against the web server, and says they are reachable because it is also on that *internal network*.

Your machine cannot resolve the internal DNS records unless you tunneled into that network.

The solution here is to

1. whitelist your network in GCP so that you can reach the cluster without exposing it to the open internet
2. You must go through each component and change the web interface address to be the public DNS

Or setup and use an SSH tunnel or VPN to any machine in the cluster

Note, Cloudera Director and Cloudera Atlus are two offerings for running and configuring CDH in the cloud